# CROSS requests and ng-repeate

Tags: angularjs, web-services, angularjs-ng-repeat, client-server, cross-domain

I'd like to decompose a Java EE web application to 2 parts, server which contains web services and made in Spring framework, and client which contains client interfaces which is made in Angular JS.

The 2 apps will have now different domaines, so the first problem was that request by angular in client were rejected. So the solution that i found in stackoverflow is that i have to enable cross requests in server and use cross requests in client. I processed by this way, and request reached server succesfully.

The problem now is that i'm using an ng-repeat to show a list that's i get from a web service, the list contains really the correct data when i check it by console.log . but ng-repeat tag is not working, and when i'm refreshing the page, this error is appearing in the console :

```
angular.js:14328 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: lCat in listeCategories track by lCat.idCategorie, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: {
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=lCat%20in%20listeCategories%20track%20by%20lCat.idCategorie&p1=undefined&p2=%7B
    at angular.js:68
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:30804)
    at $watchCollectionAction (angular.js:17677)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17814)
    at angular.js:18011
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:6111)
    at angular.js:6390
```

what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `track by $index` to avoid duplicates while repeat.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thank you @zooly, i have already found this solution, but when i'm processing with that, ng-repeat shows a lot of elements while my liste contains 4 elements

Comment: Please, share the data you want to iterate, and the `ng-repeat` section

Comment: @ESSABRI you seem to be new on Stack community. Don't post your code as a answer, but **edit** your initial question.

Comment: Btw, everything seems normal in your code. If you got a lot of elements, you may not display the right informations

Comment: no there is no problem in displayed informations, because before using cross, every think went well !!

Comment: the problem is outside informations, ng-repeat shows a loooooot of elements